# How can I make the "do" loop continue, but not infinitely in my code?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Basically, whenever I walk into the trigger it repeats the loop infinitely. I know the reason for this but I don't know the way to fix it so that it works properly. It's meant to do it until you leave the trigger.

```
public void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
        {
            
            InDamageRange = true;
            
            StartCoroutine(waiter());
        }
    
        public void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
        {
            StopCoroutine(waiter());
            InDamageRange = false;
            
        }
    
        public IEnumerator waiter()
        {
            do
            {
                yield return new WaitForSeconds(1.5f);
                player.Health = player.Health - damage;
            } while (InDamageRange != false);
            
        }
```

What can I do to make this work?

Edit: Turns out the issue was that I was trying to stop the coroutine before setting the bool to false. I swapped the two lines in OnTriggerExit and that fixed the issue, thanks for the help! :)

Comment: I'm not a Unity user, but I think `StopCoroutine()` might be waiting for your `waiter()` to finish. Try setting `InDamageRange = false;` *before* stopping the coroutine

Comment: @AndrewWilliamson technically if that `bool` is set to `false`, the coroutine should just finish and exit - no need to stop it...

Comment: Your *Edit* is still missing the point - your `StopCoroutine` call is entirely unnecessary - you're stopping a co-routine that is being started in that same call - try to follow it with breakpoints to understand it. Just because your code "works", doesn't make it right - kind of like getting into your car through the window...

Comment: @CoolBots - It does depend on your definition of "started". Until `.MoveNext()` is call it isn't really started.

Comment: @Enigmativity that's true; you phrased it much better in your answer :).  I meant to emphasize that the call to `StopCoroutine` is unnecessary, as it is being passed in a newly created `IEnumerator`, not an instance that was previously passed in to `StartCoroutine`; so there isn't anything to "stop" in that call. I am not familiar with Unity internals, but I'd venture to guess `StartCoroutine` keeps track of running coroutines in a `HashSet` which `StopCoroutine` has access to. The passed in routine in OP's case would not be in the set - a silent failure in Unity (not explained in the docs...)

Comment: I know coroutines are popular in Unity and their use of `IEnumerator` and `yield` creating a hot debate in the C# world, but if the past month is anything to go by, they should perhaps be _outlawed_. Numerous recent posts whereby **unguarded** `StartCoroutine` are spammed in either the `Update` or `OnTriggerEnter` methods leading to excessive coroutine sessions.  When you consider `Update` could be called as much as **60 times a second** or more, such code can be **hazardous**.   `StartCoroutine` may look innocent but I can't help but wonder it is as dangerous as `Application.DoEvents()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time you call `waiter()` you are creating a new instance of your `IEnumerator`. You do need to keep a reference to the original one if you want to stop it. Try this:

```
private IEnumerator _waiter;

public void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    InDamageRange = true;
    _waiter = waiter();
    StartCoroutine(_waiter);
}

public void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
{
    StopCoroutine(_waiter);
    InDamageRange = false;
}

public IEnumerator waiter()
{
    do
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1.5f);
        player.Health = player.Health - damage;
    } while (InDamageRange != false);
}
```

But given your code setting `InDamageRange = true` should have also stopped it. Is it your actual code?